# EF6 relationship mapping for objects

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

Problem (or low IQ)

I'm trying to create a EF6 mapping configuration for complex object for a Report database. It would probably be a wiser thing to rethink the structure of the objects. But the key factor is that I am creating this orginally from generated XSD scheme and I want to keep the consistency of this two things together.

This is the definition of the objects: (very simplified!)

Report is the "base class"

```
class Report  
{
    public HeaderObj headerobj {get;set;}
    public DataObj dataObj {get;set;}
}

class HeaderObj 
{
    public DateTime date {get; set;}
    public string fundID {get;set;}
}

class DataObj
{
    public ICollection<Investment> investments {get;set;}
}

class Investment
{
    //....lot of member objects here like Amount and other things..you get the drill.
}
```

This is my experiment with the mapping conf:

```
public class ReportMapping: EntityTypeConfiguration<Report>
{
    public ReportMapping()
        {
//has a composite key: date and fundid, in the object HeaderObj, probably be better off directly under Report class but as im saying, I'm trying to have consistency between the c# classes and the orginal XSD schema.

HasKey(a => new {a.headerobj.date, a.headerobj.fundID});

HasRequired(a => a.HeaderObj);

HasRequired(a => a.dataObj).WithMany(s => s.investments); <-- "computer say no here" although this does make sense to me 

        }
}
```

//...

```
Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.ICollection<Investment>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.ICollection<Report>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)
```

How can I define a correct mapping for multiple investments for the object DataObj without having this compile error?

Comment: You are trying to map the date to many investments. You probably want to try dataObj instead.

Comment: yeah that's correct. Thank's for the notification ! :)